# converting an object with HTML strings already in it as attributes back into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to display an object of arrays which hold HTML strings as HTML within my chrome ext I currently have this, where the output is `[object, object]` after converting the response via `JSON.stringify` I just get a bunch of `\n` and strings. Which i guess is right. BUT...

I know its working with a big ass string instead of an object here appears to work fine but trying to “sendResponse({})” sanitizes the HTML

If that theory’s correct, worst case could I convert “HTCP365Object” into HTML right before I do the “sendResponse()” and do a sendResponse(““) instead of a sendResponse(objectHere)

This is what I have so far.

```js
const HCP365Object = {
  sitePixels: [],
  searchPixels: [],
  emailPixels: [],
  programmaticPixels: [],
  nonHCP365Pixels: [],
};

// Function to break down the http request into our pixel url with a subset of associating query params.
const onBeforeSendHeadersListener = function (details) {
  let regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
    pixelType,
    pixelUrl = `${details.url}`,
    queryParams,
    params = {},
    match,
    colorGrade;

  if (details.url.includes('&ch=1&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Site Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-800';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=2&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Search Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-800';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=3&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Email Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-800';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=4&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Programmatic Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-800';
  } else {
    pixelType = 'Non HCP365 PP Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-gray-400';
  }

  // Splitting url's query params out to key value pairs
  while ((match = regex.exec(details.url))) {
    params[match[1]] = match[2];
  }

  // Looping through object's key value pair to place into divs
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    queryParams += `
      <div class="text-sm my-1">
        <span class="font-bold uppercase mr-1">${key}: </span>
        <span class="font-normal font-mono capitalize c-word-wrap">${value}</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  const pixelInfo = `
    <div class="element">

      <div  class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 ${colorGrade}">
        <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">${pixelType}</span>
        <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="answer hideText">
        <span id="pixel-url" class="c-word-wrap text-sm font-mono">${pixelUrl}</span>
          <span id="query-params">${queryParams}</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  `;

  // push the relevant pixel into the correct array
  if (details.url.includes('&ch=1&')) {
    HCP365Object.sitePixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=2&')) {
    HCP365Object.searchPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=3&')) {
    HCP365Object.emailPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=4&')) {
    HCP365Object.programmaticPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else {
    HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.push(pixelInfo);
  }

  return HCP365Object;
};

// Apply the function entered to each header coming from contextweb domain
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  onBeforeSendHeadersListener,
  {
    urls: ['https://*.contextweb.com/bh/*'],
  },
  ['requestHeaders']
);

// Initiate connection to send Message over to popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse(HCP365Object);
});
```

So could i do something like:

```
let markup = '<div>';
HCP365Object.sitePixels.forEach(siteMarkup => markup += siteMarkup);
HCP365Object.searchPixels.forEach(searchMarkup => markup += searchMarkup);
...
markup += '</div>';
sendResponse(markup);
```

It seems the HTML from `pixelInfo` is being stripped away within this function

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse(HCP365Object);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way

```
let markup = '<div>';
HCP365Object.sitePixels.forEach(siteMarkup => markup += siteMarkup);
HCP365Object.searchPixels.forEach(searchMarkup => markup += searchMarkup);
...
markup += '</div>';
sendResponse(markup);
```

gave me my desired result